# PHP Regular expressions replace phone number only if string length < 15

Tags: php, regex

I have a problem with phone replacement on site.

Regular expression working fine, but sometimes it replaces a part of tracking numbers, so I decided to reduce length of searching word to 15 symbols (tracking numbers have length near 18 symbols).

But I can't add this condition to the existing expression:

```
$phonePattern = '/(\+?[0-9]\W)?\(?\W?[0-9][0-9][0-9]\)?\W?[0-9][0-9][0-9]\W?[0-9][0-9]\W?[0-9][0-9]/i';
```

Is this possible to add length condition for this?

Comment: Regex has quantifiers, for example `+` for 1-inf times, `?` for 0-1, {3} for exactly 3 times or {8,15} to match between 8 to 15 times. I am sure knowing that you can come up with a solution.

Comment: You can also omit the `/i` at the end.

Comment: @OleksandrBits Please explain better how you use this pattern. From start to end of strings or for extraction inside some larger string? It's not so clear.